# VSCode Regex, looking for functions and changing them, and adding/removing arguments to them

Tags: c++, regex, visual-studio-code, replace, replaceall

Okay, I don't know how to do this, but I'm trying to use VSCode to automate a process of converting functions in a codebase to a new function, since it's deprecated. The function goes as

```
PlaySound [(sound whattoplay [, int slot [, double volume [, bool looping [, double attenuation [, bool local [, double pitch]]]]]])]
```

There is a new version of this function, all it seems to add is a new int flags.

```
StartSound [(sound whattoplay [, int slot [, int flags [, double volume [, double attenuation [, double pitch [, double starttime]]]]]])]
```

So, in the case i have something like

```
PlaySound("STHR", CHAN_AUTO, 1.0, false, ATTN_NONE);
```

What is the way I could replace all functions like this and similar to add that new argument? (and remove the older arguments) It would look like:

```
StartSound("STHR", CHAN_AUTO, CHANF_DEFAULT, 1.0, ATTN_NONE);
```

I tried doing something with

```
PlaySound[(][^)]+[,][^)]+[)]
```

But I can't seem to figure it out. What is the way to do this? Is it even possible with regex?

Answer (score 0):

Search

```
PlaySound\(([^,)]+)(, [^,)]+)?(, [^,)]+)?(, [^,)]+)?(, [^,)]+)?(, [^,)]+)?(, [^,)]+)?\);
```

Replace

```
StartSound($1$2, CHANF_DEFAULT$3$5$7);
```

And then perform a search for `PlaySound` to see if all your use cases have the same formatting.